# How to ensure users only embed SoundCloud iFrame?

Tags: coldfusion, jsoup, soundcloud, railo

I am building a social networking website for musicians and I would like them to be able to enter the embed code provided by SoundCloud, so that they may have a sound clip on their posts.

However, I am unsure how I would sanitise the input, to ensure that it's only a SoundCloud `iframe` embed code that they enter. I want to avoid them pasting in embed code for say, YouTube or anything else for that matter.

An example embed code from SoundCloud looks like:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F85146642"></iframe>
```

I am using the HTML parser, jSoup to sanitise input.

The key fragment to this is the `src` content:
https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F85146642

One possibility I thought of, was to extract the `src` parameters value and then rebuild the `iframe` myself, this way, only storing the URL and ensuring that any HTML output to the browser is that which I have created myself. Doing this may also allow me to run checks on the domain name etc.

I'm wondering what the best approach would be for this?

Appreciate any input you may have.

Thanks,
Michael.

PS - I am using Railo (ColdFusion server) and the Java jSoup library, but I guess the same principles would apply regardless of what language one would use.

Comment: I would always sanitize any kind of data going into the src of an iframe. You could grab the src attribute and apply a regular expression check against it.

That being said, soundcloud has an html5 and jquery option (stratus) to aleady embed soundcloud items into your site. I would investigate that before rolling my own iframe, given the nature of iframes. Personal opinion anyhow.

Comment: @DanaKowalski I don't mind using the default SoundCloud iframe approach, but I'm just trying to see how I can make sure that the code inserted is indeed a SoundCloud widget. I think the best option is to grab the URL, check it etc, then reconstruct the iframe (the same way they did it). That way, I can sanitise the input down to a URL and avoid any potentially malicious code in the process. Any further thoughts welcome.

Comment: Your current proposal seems fine - jSoup can handle the HTML protection, whilst you handle the URL protection/verification (i.e. make sure it's the right domain and only contains expected character - no nulls or control chars that might cause problems).

Comment: Yes, you can do that if you have the track url, another way could be to store the sc username and using their api to get a tracklist from the user - that you can make selectable.